# Scroll to horizontally overflowed element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, overflow

Could anyone suggest how I can define whether a tab is overflowed and how I can scroll to that tab, thus it become not overflowed?

The code snippet below visualizes the problem. The "Four" tab is hidden, and if this tab would be active, the user would have no clue that the "Four" tab is selected on a small device. I'm currently using AngularJS as main framework.

```css
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.navigation > a {
  min-width: 200px;
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation > a:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.navigation > a:hover, .navigation > a:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='navigation'>
  <a>One</a>
  <a>Two</a>
  <a>Three</a>
  <a>Four</a>
</div>
```

Comment: How can a user click 'Four' without scrolling in the first place?

Comment: @sol It could be active from something other than being directly clicked,  like a link.

Comment: @freginold I see, fair point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can first determine the active tab and get its offset position (from left) and apply that value to the scroll (eg: using jQuery scrollLeft) and this will force the scrollbar to scroll to the active tab.